# Android App installed through Signed APK from Eclipse is not opening

Tags: android, eclipse, installation, apk

I am creating a signed APK.

Through eclipse I was able to create successfully install an app on to my Samsung Tablet. I used the same keystore to create another signed APK and install it and open it. I am able to install but not able to open it errors out. "Unfortunately App Name has stopped"

No Idea why it is not working. This has Google Maps. I am able to install the same app through eclipse via USB and open it. Works great. But when i try to make APK and install it, it fails to open.

Does anybody have a clue why? I'm not sure where the Google key should go or how to debug this issue any help would be appreciated

Comment: **"not sure ... or how to debug this issue"** - The first thing any Android developer should learn is how to use logcat. if your app is closing there will be errors in logcat - connect your device to your computer, open the DDMS or Debug perspectives and launch the app on your device then copy/paste the logcat data here.

Comment: Sorry Squonk, I think you misunderstood what I am asking hakanostrom might be right on his answer. I took over someone else application and successfully finished the development but I have no documentation on how they did APK file creation if I follow the normal way that is given by android development the apk file after installation is not opening. so I am in the process of recreating the keystore and see that will help but I need to learn many stuff before I can do that because I see there is a KeyTool command and Google Key

Comment: So I am trying to create a google key and associate that with my new keystore but reading docs if you have any links please do share

Comment: My point is related to how StackOverflow works. If you have a programming problem, don't just describe it - post code and also (for Android) post logcat output. Trust me - there will be errors logged. As I said, however, the most important thing for you to learn is how to use logcat - you'll be able to solve the majority of your programming problems that way without having to ask questions here.

Comment: I clearly understand how StackOverflow works.And I clearly told you this is not a programming issue. Please if you dont know how to solve my issue please stop spamming. I told you the other guy is in the right direction.

Comment: I didn't get 22K+ reputation here on StackOverflow by "spamming" or posting deliberately annoying/provocative comments. I got it by helping people who posted questions with sufficient detail for it to be possible to answer their questions. In some cases I try to persuade people to post more detail as the original question only has enough to guess what the solution might be. The "other guy" (hakanostrom) starts his answer with "Probably..." and if his answer is really "in the right direction" why haven't you upvoted or accepted it? Don't worry - I won't bother trying to help you again.

Comment: @Renaissance Please use `backticks` only for formatting `code`, not for `highlighting` `keywords`

Comment: @Renaissance Many topics on meta, e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right . Let's keep this meta-discussion away from this question though.

Comment: agreed. lets delete the comments

Comment: @Squonk I am not rejecting your point, If I have programming question I will explain the way you are asking It makes much sense. The issue itself is not programming. I successfully build the project and I install it using Eclipse everything is fine. I see there is a debug.keystore in the project and then Google key is also there. I also see a command for KeyTool. So since everything is working fine. Now I am trying to make the APK so I can distribute the File.

Comment: When I create APK it gave me logcat error saying some classes are deprecated so I fixed those error and the APK got created successfully. then I moved that APK to my tablet and installed. All Sucess up until this point. then I try to open it errors out. So No idea what the issue is. because I dont know how to check what is wrong. For this I used Debug May be the word choice is wrong but I explained exactly what happens. I would appreciate if you can help me, I am struggling with this for sometime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I read some article I found what really is going on

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.test.data.TestProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.data.TestProvider

So I tried so many suggestions like clean and build, setting java class path on properties, changing proguard and many more but this issue is not going away.

Thanks for those that helped me up to this.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your Google maps key are bound to your eclipse debug keystore. If you export a app from Eclipse maybe you used another keystore.  And then you also need another Google maps key.